# Using Azure App Config -> Want to allow local config to override for devs

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, azure-app-configuration

I have a Blazor server app.  It's using Azure App Config to config values now - but I optionally want to allow devs to override local.

The problem I'm running into is CreateDefaultBuilder loads the config from local appsettings.json/env/et al first, then the Azure App Config values load - over the local settings if they are present (which is normally what I want).

I see the code for [CreateDefaultBuilder](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L156), and I could  just copy what's there to my code (when I want this dev behavior) after Azure App Config loads (which should overrride any values from Azure App Config that are in the local settings.  I could just not load the Azure App Config values at all, optionally, but I rather just let the dev override what they want local and then get the rest from the  Azure App Config

This seem clunky.  Any suggestions for a better way to do this?

My code that deals with this:

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
             {
                 certThumbprint = context.Configuration.GetValue<string>("CertificateThumbprint");
                 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(certThumbprint) == false)
                 {
                     var kestrelOptions = context.Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel");
                     if (kestrelOptions != null && kestrelOptions.Value != null)
                     {
                         services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(kestrelOptions);
                     }
                 }
             })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                var settings = config.Build();
                var credentials = new DefaultAzureCredential(false);
                config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
                {
                    
                    var azAppConfigurationURI = settings.GetValue<string>("AzAppConfigurationURI");
                    var envName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

                    //options.Connect(new Uri(azAppConfigurationURI), credentials)                        
                    options.Connect("Endpoint = end + key ") // Removed for this sample                       
                    .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
                    {
                        kv.SetCredential(credentials);
                    })
                    .ConfigureRefresh(refresh =>
                    {
                        refresh.Register("test", refreshAll: true)
                        .SetCacheExpiration(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
                        
                    })                        
                   .UseFeatureFlags((featureFlagOptions =>
                   {
                       featureFlagOptions.Label = envName;
                       featureFlagOptions.CacheExpirationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);                           
                   }
                   ));
                });
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStaticWebAssets();
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
                {
                    // Set properties and call methods on options
                    serverOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(listenOptions =>
                    {
                        // certificate is an X509Certificate2
                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(certThumbprint) == false)
                        {
                            listenOptions.ServerCertificate = GetCertificateFromStore(certThumbprint);
                        }
                    });

                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Thanks!
-Greg

Answer (score 2):

Just use appsettings.development.json.

If you are talking about Azure App Services then look into Deployment Slots.

Comment: As far as I can tell, when you call CreateDefaultBuilder it loads settings form the json files. When you then call to get the Azure App Config (ConfigureAppConfiguration) it will overwrite any common keys.  I'd like to have it not do that (but still use Azure App Config when there isn't a dup)

Comment: @Greg but i think you are missing the point of the setup. The azure settings override for security reasons. You dont have the deployed settings in source control. If you want devs to override local just use appsettings.development.json and run locally or give them their own Deployment Slot

Comment: For anyone confused by this answer, you would have to _not_ have a corresponding `Development` label in the Azure App Config.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @j-campbell's answer I created an extension for re-ordering the config sources so the appsettings take priority, which means a developer can override the config values by adding a key-value in appsettings.json.

```
public static IConfigurationBuilder PrioritizeAppSettings(this IConfigurationBuilder builder)
{
    var appsettings = builder.Sources.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(JsonConfigurationSource)).ToList();
    foreach (var source in appsettings)
    {
        builder.Sources.Remove(source);
        builder.Sources.Add(source);
    }
    return builder;
}
```

Then call the extension at the end of ConfigureAppConfiguration:

```
config.PrioritizeAppSettings();
```

It just unloads the json sources and reloads them again, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [IConfigurationBuilder.Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfigurationbuilder.sources?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfigurationBuilder_Sources) to reorder the configuration sources in your configuration builder. This will allow you to set the precedence that you'd like. You could check if the environment is dev, if so perform the re-ordering. Otherwise just use the default ordering.